# Binance API call not working in Lavavel Controller

Tags: laravel, binance

I am writing a laravel controller which calls Binance PHP APIs.

The PHP API works perfect if run individually from command line, e.g.,
php price.php

> +++++++price.php++++++++
>
> $api = new \Binance\API($api_key, $api_secret);
>
> // Get all of your positions, including estimated BTC value
> $price =$api->price("BNBBTC"); print_r($price);
>
> +++++++price.php+++++++++

However, if I call the api funcion price() from laravel controller, nothing shows up, no errors etc. I can dd($binance_api) and it returned the object is created successfully with all the correct API key/secret.

> Class PriceController extends Controller{
> public function price
> (Request $request){
>
> $api_key = "xxxxxxx";
>
> $api_secret = "xxxxxxxx";
>
> ```
> $binance_api = new \Binance\API($api_key, $api_secret);
>
> $price = $binance_api->price("BNBBTC");
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Comment: in the API class definition,

public function price()
    {
        return $this->priceData($this->httpRequest("v3/ticker/price"));
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value

```
Class PriceController extends Controller{
  public function price (Request $request){
    $api_key = "xxxxxxx";
    $api_secret = "xxxxxxxx";
    $binance_api = new \Binance\API($api_key, $api_secret);
    $price = $binance_api->price("BNBBTC");
    return $price;
  }
}
```

Comment: i found the rootcause was something else. But thank you for the comment.